# UmbracoExamine ExternalIndexer Cannot index queue items, the index is currently locked

Tags: umbraco

We get this error a lot on our Umbraco site, also we've noticed that when we publish content, it doesn't actually publish it, then I check the log and I see this error message.

Is this because there maybe more than one admin user logged in at one time?

Pete

Answer (score 0):

Having more than one admin user logged in at the same time is not a problem at all. There's plenty of running sites with *many* backoffice users logged in and editing at the same time. The only case where this could give an issue is the fact that if you have two users load up the same item in the backoffice and one makes changes and saves.. and the other one then saves without reloading first, the changes from user1 will be overwritten by whatever was loaded when user2 loaded up the page.

One thing that could lock up your indexes however is having multiple sites run off the same index files (which is NOT supported) - so make sure you're not doing this. I've seen some people forgetting having an old IIS test site configured in the same folder after going in production which could bring up this issue.

Another thing that I usually do is exclude the index folders from both anti-virus scanning and the windows indexing service, as I've seen both of these take temporary file locks which sometimes interfere with umbraco's access to the index files. The indexing can be turned off by right-clicking the specific folder in explorer, selecting properties > advanced > uncheck the 'allow files to be indexed'.